# How to use params of object

Tags: c#

I have an error in this code , the error in the foreach loop and params of object in method.

This is my code:

```
class car
{
    private int Id;
    private string make;
    private string model;
    private Colore c;
    private int value;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string make { get; set;  }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }

    public void Display(params car[] list)
    {
        int summ=0;
        foreach(car i in list)
            Console.WriteLine(list[i].value);
        foreach (car i in list)
            summ += list[i].value;
        Console.WriteLine(summ); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Should Colore be Color? Is list null? Your foreach syntax looks wrong - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist <----- should probably check this out

Comment: change `Console.WriteLine(list[i].value);` to `Console.WriteLine(i.value);`

Comment: @Liath and what is in the first code line? `class car`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use a foreach to loop in the car[] array, you should use the object directly:

```
int summ=0;
foreach (car i in list)
{
   summ += i.value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to confuse `for` and `foreach` loops.

On a basic level, `for` iterates over indices of an array, and gives you a current index on each iteration. So you would do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(list[i].value);
```

`foreach`, on the other hand, iterates over the elements of an array themselves, and gives you a current element. Here is how it can be used

```
foreach(car i in list)
    Console.WriteLine(i.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of the `params` argument is fine. There are other errors, however.

1. You cannot have a property with the same name as a private field

```
public string make { get; set;  }
private string make;
```

Since you've already used an automatic property `{get; set;}`, you do not need to define the backing field at all (i.e. just delete `private string make;`

2. You have also misunderstood the use of `foreach` - it enumerates the array and thus avoids the need to apply an indexer to the array:

```
foreach (car i in list)
    Console.WriteLine(i.make);
```

Here, as you iterate the array, `i` will return a reference to each `car` object in the params array. The variable would be better named as `car`, and `list` is not an ideal name for the `params` argument given that it is actually an `array`.

Also, given that Display doesn't interact with `this` in any way, it could be made static, or even an external extension method, e.g. you could change change your code to this (I've taken some liberty with variable naming conventions):

```
class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set;  }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static void Display(params car[] cars)
    {
        int summ=0;
        foreach(var car in cars)
            Console.WriteLine(car.Value);
        foreach (car i in list)
            summ += car.Value;
        Console.WriteLine(summ); 
    } 
}
```

And call like so:

```
Car.Display(new Car{Make = "Toyota", Value = 1000}, 
            new Car{Make = "Ferrari", Value = 5000});
```